# C# set property values in "bulk" (by excluding)

Tags: c#

In C# I have several classes where I have the following "logic":

```
 //objA and objB are instances of the same class
 objA.Property1 = objB.Property1;
 objA.Property2 = objB.Property2;
 objA.Property3 = objB.Property3;
 objA.Property4 = objB.Property4;
 .....
 objA.Property40 = objB.Property40;
```

I do not want to apply the value to all the properties (but a big part of them).

This is getting repetitive and if somehow the "class" changes where there is a new property there is no compilation error and if the programmer does not pay attention there will be a bug because we will be losing that property change.....

I was wondering if there is a way to the following:

--> Apply the value of all the properties EXCLUDING the ones that specifically point, something like:

```
    //possible syntax 
    objA.SetAllPropertiesLess(objB, x => x.Id && x.CreateDate && x.IsDeleted);
```

Does not need to be so "fancy" like this one, but for starting I would like to know if there is already something similar in the .NET framework, then if not, perhaps someone would already have an implementation (lightweight/fast).

Comment: Try looking at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: Sounds like a job for Automapper - or alternatively roll your own generic property copying tool using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) and [conditional mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping).

Answer (score 3):

Use AutoMapper.

Install it from nuget.org by following command:

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper
```

Then import it in class file and use it like below:

```
CreateMap<objA, objB>().ForDestinationMember(x => x.IsDeleted, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you have any doubt.